# Quiz results/score are over 100 points

Tags: 7, users, quiz

I have a quiz with 5 questions of 10 points each one. When I score them, some exams save the result of the quiz with more than 100 points.

[image]

As you can see, I have an exam with 112 but if I open:

[image]

Look that the total score is 92% (but his score is 112).

In the other hand, the user with 100 scores is right.

So, as summary of this, I've got users with right total score but some of them have a wrong final score.

The module that I'm using is Quiz drupal.org/project/quiz version 7.x-5.0-alpha9.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bugreport to whatever module you are using. And even if bugreports weren't defined off-topic here, you didn't post relevant data - link to module you are using, definition of your quiz, information on debug steps you already did, and so on.

Comment: The module that I'm using is Quiz https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz version 7.x-5.0-alpha9. Maybe it can be a common error of the module. I haven't just found about it.

Comment: Alpha versions are known to have bugs. They are early tests, before beta ("I hope there are no bugs") and release candidate ("I believe there are no bugs, but let's test one last time")

Comment: @Mołot ... You're mostly right, except when there are alfa versions used in like 30K sites, such as https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/conditional_fields ... A sample of "versions" that are not correctly named anymore I think, would you agree that most of these 30K sites just ASSUME there are no bugs?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens nope. All we know is that they assume quality level they are willing to accept. Apart from that, it's either a bug report or question lacks data needed to answer, version number on module changes nothing.

Comment: @Mołot: agree with your last comment. But my prior comment was only to point out that for some modules those alfa, beta, rc indications are not correctly named (because mostly the maintainer never "called it a real release" so far). You don't want a dozen (of dozens ...) of similar modules with a similar release qualifier, do you?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens if maintainer don't care enough to bump version to rc or stable, I think it should be a reason to be cautious and have development manhours available... Because actual big fixes take even more time and effort, so if he missed easy tasks, he just might missed harder ones, too.

Comment: @Mołot : that might be true, but know that often it is not a matter of "don't care", but rather "whenever such maintainer has time to do so" ... Which is especially true for those thousands of maintainers who "contribute" part of their spare time to develop, maintain (and support ...) their module(s). But maybe those "development manhours available" that you mean could be implemented by "sponsoring" (or "donating to")  those spare time contributors (so that they can make their living from it some day also ...). Back to the original question maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answer. Finally, I've achived to solve the problem. At first, this bug comes from last versions.

If you create in this module a Long Question which max score is 0, it creates an inconsistency because you cannot divide by 0.

Some months ago, I found a patch to solve it:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2394759

But it's incomplete, because the module save the scores of each question in database and then it updates the total score adding the score of each one.

So, the way to solve that is changing the next lines in the same file that the patch file (**../question_types/long_answer/long_answer.module**):

```
db_update('quiz_node_results_answer')
  ->fields(array(
     'points_awarded' => $points_awarded,
     'is_correct' => $is_correct,
))
```

to

```
db_update('quiz_node_results_answer')
  ->fields(array(
     'points_awarded' => $calculated_score,
     'is_correct' => $is_correct,
))
```

To note the change is the variable **$points_awarded** for the variable calculated in the patch: **$calculated_score**.

With these changes, the patch is complete and everything is working.